# Can I disable min, max in STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I use one library which is very important and untouchable.
The problem is that library declare min, max function,
so when I include STL header in project, they conflict.
I want to disable min, max function in STL (like #define NOMNMAX) if I could.
If I can't, what would be solution?

Important :
Sorry, It's not Macro. Two functions are template functions.

like

```
template<T>
T min(const T& a, const T& b) { a < b ? a : b; }
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: "Hi, I use one library which is very important and untouchable." You mean the Standard Library right? :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The min and max functions are defined in the `std` namespace, so this code should not compile:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int n = min( 1, 2 );
}
```

If it does, your Standard Library is non-compliant. Also, your important and untouchable library should be declaring it's functions in a namespace. If it isn't. complain loudly to the vendor.

**Edit:** As these functions are presumably in a header file, you can touch them. So a hack would be to remove the templates from the header and replace them with the following:

```
using std::min;
using std::max;
```

though why the writers of the library felt the need to define these templates is anyone's guess.

Comment: I'm guessing the library is declaring min/max as macros, so namespaces might not help

Comment: @nikie Any library that declares min & max as publicly available macros wants taking out and shooting. But you may well be right.

Comment: Another possibility is that the OP has a `using namespace std` somewhere.

Comment: Surely no one would #define min and max either. And no one would want to disable `std::min`/`std::max` when a conflict arises because of it. If only we could rely on developers to do the right thing. ;)

Comment: "Any library that declares min & max as macros wants shooting." Like the...charming people...at Microsoft who wrote the Windows API?

Answer (score 6):

As both `min` and `max` (and every other standard library member) are defined in `std` namespace, you just mustn't import that namespace, i.e. don't use `using namespace std;`. You can still use STL, by explicit namespace resultion, eg. `std::max`, `std::cout` etc.

Comment: Wouldn't matter, would it? You don't cause a conflict by merely writing `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes have problems with something like that as well, because iirc OpenCV #defines its own min/max, as well as i think does windows.h.
Usually I help myself by simply

```
#undef min
#undef max
```

Neil is right, though, as min is in std:: namespace. For me the problem arises, that with some headers #defining min/max, i can't even use std::min()

Answer (score 3):

If your untouchable library is not in a namespace, you could force the lookup to use global scope, rather than std:

```
int i = ::min<int>(1,2);
```

A better solution would be to remove

```
using namespace std
```

and get your library in a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Define `NOMINMAX`, and you won't get either of these functions.

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

Comment: Assuming his vendor provides such functionality. He never said it was Windows, which is where `NOMINMAX` is generally used. (In fact, he said he wanted something like it, implying it doesn't exist.)

Comment: Yeah he didn't mention, I don't really use C++ on Linux, but I used to define this macro all the time on Windoze.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing your libary defines min/max as macros, so the fact that STL min/min are in a namespace won't help. You could try this:

```
#define max STL_MAX
#define min STL_MIN
#include <algorithm>
#undef min
#undef max
```

That way, min and max are translated to something else while algorithm is compiled. Of course this only works if you include algorithm before your library.

Comment: Why does the STL namespace not help? "max()" will never call the STL max() (unless one uses using namespace std;, which is a bad idea anyway).

Comment: @Frank: the preprocessor ignores namespaces. So if you include a header that `#define`s min/max, then include STL, the preprocessor will replace min/max in the STL header, and the STL header won't compile.